# Does CP affect size when evolving?

Tags: pokemon-go

Whenever I evolve a low CP Pokemon, it becomes XS. Does evolving a high CP Pokemon give it XL weight/height?

I don't have enough candy or stardust to test it myself.

Answer (score 2):

A Pokémon's size and weight are by no means linked to neither the CP nor HP. They do not, as of yet, serve any practical purpose.

Answer (score 0):

XS and XL are completely separate from CP. XS and XL simply effect how much hp a pokemon has and how fast it attacks. XS pokemon attack faster but has lower hp and vice versa for XL. If I'm not mistaken XS and XL are completely random even after evolution.

In the end CP matters the most as you are leveling up. You might start to care about XS vs XL once you get into serious gym battles and everyone is around max CP.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4s2ij5/what_your_pokemon_go_stat_card_means/d55zxsx?st=iqolu1o4&sh=ce8f37ac)

Comment: XL/XS wouldn't affect HP. Their IVs are what determine HP.

Answer (score -1):

I just evolved a high CP XL Magikarp and it turned into a high CP XS Gyarados. So no CP does not affect size.

Answer (score -1):

Every xl weight evolves into a xs weight and it'll get a cp boost

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: Just something I figured out playing the game, I've only tried it out on a few Pokemon but the result are always the same.

Comment: i haven't had the same results, that is why I think a source is needed :)

Comment: I have noticed XL evolving into XS sometimes but that has no bearing on CP